# Why does BigQuery API call take so long?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to query BigQuery use the BigQuery API with the Python client library.

However, for some reason, my query seems to "hang" for about 150 seconds when calling the BigQuery API, i.e., at the following line (see below for full code sample):
`results = client.query(query)`

*Note: it doesn't matter what the actual query is. Therefore, in my sample  code below, I'm just putting `SELECT 1` as a query.*

Interestingly, there is only a delay for the first query -  all subsequent queries are as fast as expected.

I've checked the query time in the Query History for BQ, and it confirms that all of the queries take less than a second. So it's definitely not the actual query that's taking so long, but something else.

I'm guessing that this may somehow related to the authentication, but I'm not sure why that would be or if I'm doing anything wrong - or how it can be sped up, most importantly.

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# IMPORTS
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os 
from datetime import datetime

print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}: Starting script...")

# INIT BQ
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "my_credentials.json"
client = bigquery.Client()

# QUERY 1
print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}: Starting query 1...")

query1 = """SELECT 1 AS mycol LIMIT 1"""

print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}: Making API request...")
results1 = client.query(query1) # <-- this is where the 150s delay happens

for row in results1:
    print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}: Results: {row['mycol']}")

# QUERY 2
print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}: Starting query 2...")

query2 = """SELECT 2 AS mycol LIMIT 1"""

print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}: Making API request...")
results2 = client.query(query2) # <-- this is super-quick

for row in results2:
    print(f"{datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')}: Results: {row['mycol']}")

#EOF
```

This is the output (running this on my local machine):

```
22:33:48: Starting script...
22:33:48: Starting query 1...
22:33:48: Making API request... # <-- this is taking ~150s
22:36:24: Results: 1
22:36:24: Starting query 2...
22:36:24: Making API request...
22:36:26: Results: 2
```

Comment: What's in the response headers? Especially regarding the rate limits of platform? What happens during the authorization (This is clearly the reason)? How many of actual requests happening within the first query?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that. Could you let me know how to edit my code to let you know?

Comment: Can you enable verbose logging to see what's wrong? My advice would be to get any logging info and, if you can't figure it out from there, file an issue on GitHub to raise it as a potential bug!

Comment: How do I enable verbose logging?

Comment: Do you have special configuration in your project or your organisation? Slots and reservation?

Comment: No, no such things.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect cloud [logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring#logs) for this particular Bigquery job and check out the query timings?

Comment: I have encountered the same problem and was able to narrow down to the client initialization: `client = bigquery.Client()` is taking ~3 seconds. I'm still trying to figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after two days of trying to find a solution, the exact same script, which took 160 seconds yesterday, is now running in about 4 seconds. It would seem that there was something wrong on Google's side of things.